# Blender fails to start at all (version 2.80, Windows 10 x64) - why?

Tags: installation

I tried uninstall-reinstall, tried 2.79b, and tried the portable version. Also tried running Blender.exe as Administrator, and checked for display drivers.

I am running Windows 10 x64 Enterprise. Have never installed Blender before.

I am using the built-in Intel graphics, on a i7-6700K CPU on an Asus Maximus XIII Extreme motherboard with 32GB of RAM.

What it does is show a terminal-window for about 5 seconds. I've tried capturing it to see what text it's showing but it's too brief.

Why does this program not run?

Feeling very discouraged. Any helpful help is appreciated - thank you.
James

Comment: Your integrated graphics seem to fulfill the minimum requirements to run Blender 2.8. You could check if there is an updated graphics driver available, which could resolve the problem. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29074/Intel-Graphics-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers?product=88195

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic for [blender.se].  You could ask on https://blender.chat

Answer (score 0):

same OS + memory 32GB, close down all other non-essential programs that are running in background. I had the same issue, nothing but a black screen for 15-30 secs,, but finally the blender main screen came up. I had to close it, then close some stuff running in the background ( had some downloads going, watching a video, but once I shut those down, it started without issue & didnt stop responding..

Comment: Thank you pakrat, but this has not helped despite many attempts.